# GDI+ drawing with multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, gdi+

**Disclaimer: I'm somewhat of a noob when it comes to multi-threading. I've read stuff online, have done some simple multi-threading examples.**

I've got a Win32 app that wants to draw the stuff in one thread and handle the Win32 messages in another thread. However, after the windows is created and the threads start, it hangs. I have a hunch that it may have to do with **WaitForMultipleObjects()**, but I don't know how to make it right. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? Should I suspend and resume threads?

Here's my code:

WinAPI:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR szCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    /* initialization blah blah */

    zgE->startThreads(); // <--- starts the 2 threads

    WaitForMultipleObjects(zgE->getThreadsNo(), zgE->getThreads(), TRUE, INFINITE);
    return TRUE;
}
```

This is how I start the threads:

```
void zgEngine::startThreads()
{
    /* allocation and stuff, blah blah blah */

    m_arrThreads[m_nThreads++] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, &zgEngine::handleMsg, (void*)this, NULL, NULL);
    m_arrThreads[m_nThreads++] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, &zgEngine::drawObjects, (void*)this, NULL, NULL);

    assert(m_nThreads <= THREADS_NO);
}
```

And the 2 functions that draw & handle messages are quite simplist. A while loop in each of them.

```
// draw function
DWORD WINAPI zgEngine::drawObjects(LPVOID lpParam)
{    
    while (true)
    {
        /* draw stuff - valid code that if called outside this function
           works as intended  */
    }

    return TRUE;
}

// message handler function
DWORD WINAPI zgEngine::handleMsg(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    MSG msg;
    while (true)
    {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            // Process the message
            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
                break;

            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

**When I don't use threads and remove the "while (true)" in drawObjects(), but leave the code (to be executed only once), don't call handleMsg() and make WinMain like in the example below, it works like a charm.**

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR szCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    /* initialization blah blah */

    MSG msg;
    while (true)
    {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            // Process the message
            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
                break;

            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        } else {
             zgEngine::DrawObjects(zgE);
        } 
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

**Later edit: from what I've seen, PeekMessage() always returns 0 :(**

Comment: There is a rumor that Windows user32 and gdi are thread-safe.  I'm skeptical, but it is *very* hard to prove.  Nobody knows how to keep their own program thread-safe for *every* window and *every* message.  Clearly yours is not, you make no attempt to interlock the message dispatching with the drawing.   You are much better off not trying, at best you might make rendering in a back-buffer work and page-flip it.  With proper locking you can probably get that to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote from [`PeekMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644943%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on Microsofts website:

> A handle to the window whose messages are to be retrieved. The window
>   must belong to the current thread.
>
> If hWnd is NULL, PeekMessage retrieves messages for any window that
>   belongs to the current thread, and any messages on the current
>   thread's message queue whose hwnd value is NULL (see the MSG
>   structure). Therefore if hWnd is NULL, both window messages and thread
>   messages are processed.
>
> If hWnd is -1, PeekMessage retrieves only messages on the current
>   thread's message queue whose hwnd value is NULL, that is, thread
>   messages as posted by PostMessage (when the hWnd parameter is NULL) or
>   PostThreadMessage.

I suspect the thread doesn't have a "current window", and the "current threads message queue" isn't the one that Windows actually posts the messages onto as the default thread. This is only an assumption, since it is entirely possible that there are other problems (as well?) with your approach. But I believe this is a main portion of where the problem lies.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up on the window. You're right, it slipped by me. However, the app still hangs :(. PeekMessage() keeps on returning 0.

Comment: And is there something sending messages to the queue you are looking at?

Comment: Well messages should be sent/received when the window gets activated or not, or when it's destroyed etc. These are handled by my WndProc(). Howeever, after the app starts, the window becomes unresponsive. The code is pretty simply written, no thread-safe (just experimenting with multi-threading), so there may be a ton of bugs.

Comment: The window's owned by the main thread (WinMain()), but stored in a global object. And I've also used AttachThreadInput() to attach the 2 threads to the main one.

Comment: So, as far as I can tell, this will only work if the sender/poster of the message knows the ID of your thread - which is unlikely if you haven't done something to achieve that. I suspect you need to actually "repost" the messages from your main thread. I don't know for sure, but that's how I read the text about `PostMessage`, `PostThreadMessage` and `PeekMessage`. In particular there are several mentions of "in the message queue of the thread ..." - to me, this says that the message is put into a "per thread" queue as soon as it is being posted or sent, and PeekMessage only looks in its own

Comment: In order to keep the code simple, I moved the PeekMessage() into the main thread which now de-hangs the app even if the other thread is continuously. However, if I WaitForMultipleObject() INFINITE-ly, it still hangs, but that's expected. I'll use a timeout interval and suspend and resume the other thread from time to time.

Comment: Would it not be a better idea to have a third thread, simply doing the `WaitForMultipleObject`, and then send a message to the main thread when the wait is "released". By using a timeout, you are introducing lag to your application, which is not good - and if the timeout is short enough, it will also (unnecessarily) slurp CPU all the time.